# Were Confederate pikes just a curious item to laugh at?

Tags: american-civil-war, confederacy

If you check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19YnxZwNOmc) you can see many Confederate pikes being unearthed. There are also other videos featuring high-tech Confederate [pikes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-XXeNfmcxM). Were these meant just to entertain troops in the field? There are no instances I'm aware of, where the pike was used in anger against the Yankee invader.

EDIT:
If you watch the first video, you will see, that the pikes were made in 1865. How could the discussion about their use and their manufacture continue up until the end of the American civil war without actual use in the field?

Comment: Have you ever worked with government procurement?  I used to work on a government study - every year when we submitted it, the Secretary of the Navy asked us to discontinue the study.  Apparently he wasn't senior enough to actually change the tasking.  The government purchases things because constituents require them to, not because they fulfill a mission, requirement or need.

Comment: Sure, but the pikes were actually being manufactured, not just studied. Close to the end of the war.

Comment: Pikes were used in cavalry, until 1930th. You cannot really shoot a rifle effectively from horseback (contrary to what the movies tend to show).

Comment: @Alex Those are lances.

Comment: If I have a government contract to produce pikes, I'm not going to stop producing pikes simply because they're not useful.  The use of the contract is to pay my employees.  You can stack them in artisanal fashion for all I care.  </enough of my wan attempts at humor>

Comment: Csa$ was worth almost nothing at the end of the war, partially due to Yankee counterfeiting, I don't think money mattered much close to the end.

Comment: Rebel pikes used to "entertain troops in the field"?  I suspect that many Rebels would cry instead of laugh over the thought of being armed with pikes in battle.  Of course it is better to fight with a pike than to fight bare handed in battle.  And just as bayonet charges and saber charges scared enemy troops and sometimes made them break and run, a pike charge could scare enemy troops and might make them break and run.

Comment: You're wrong. The Confederates had muskets to spare. There is an account from the siege of Petersburg, where Confederate soldiers were issued with 2 muskets per soldier to shoot at charging Federals. This makes the existence of pikes all the more perplexing.

Comment: @MAGolding + they could obtain a firearm from their home state or buy it from a [gunsmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Hinson), obtain it from their family or obtain a captured firearm.

Answer (score 3):

No. In the "killer Angels," there was a discussion about how Stonewall Jackson had ordered pikes for his troops (that were never used before he was killed).

The main rifle used by the Union Army in the Civil War was the [Springfield Rifle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/springfield-rifle), which was a single shot, not a repeating, weapon. (The Confederates used single-shot Enfields). What gave "guns" a large part of their value up to the end of the 19th century was the [bayonets.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/why-were-troops-with-bayonets-often-effective-against-enemy-cavalry-even-though/15395#15395)

If you take that thought along a certain line, you might conclude that "stabbing" weapons would be useful in that kind of a war. Jackson, for one, wasn't big on "firepower." His infantry was described as ["foot cavalry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_cavalry), which is to say that he relied on the toughness and endurance of his troops more than their weaponry. He and other Confederate commanders. thought that the main weakness of contemporary blade weapons was that they were too single purpose; using elaborate, multifunctional pikes would take care of that. The most famous Confederate command during Pickett's charges was ["Give 'em cold steel, boys."](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/778482) General Armistead was referring to bayonets.

Comment: Springfield, as in *Springfield Massachusetts*; I think not. The Confederate Army mostly used the *British Pattern 1853 Enfield*.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that Charles XII of Sweden was the last major commander to use the pike, in the early 18th century (it was considered oldfashioned by then as well, but turned out to be surprisingly effective). Also, you've repeated one of your links.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Clarified that to say that the Union used Springfields, and the Confederates Enfields. Added an apposition to state my "real" point that Springfields were not repeating weapons, which is to say that stabbing weapons such as bayonets and"pikes" had some usefulness against them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @andejons: As I remember, they didn't actually use them, only "thought about" using them. But Jackson would have been comfortable with Charles XII's mindset, "Att gaa paa." (Jag talar lite Svensk.) Basically stabbing weapons would not become "secondary" until the advent of repeating weapons.

Comment: `they didn't actually use them` Charles XII definitely made use of infantry pikes, at the very least, in the Battle of Poltava (1709). However, even then pikes were only useful to cover against enemy cavalry.

Comment: I don't think you have actually answered my question. I know about the Stonewall Jackson discussion and that Lee agreed to the use of the pikes, but if you look at the first video, you will see, that the pikes were made in 1865, when Jackson was long deceased. How could the "discussion" about the use of the pikes continue until the end of the war? I would expect some use by then, or that the production of pikes would cease.

Comment: @user1095108: I did my best to answer your original question. You just asked a followup question as to why the debate continued without being resolved, and production continued. I can't answer a question about how the Confederate bureaucracy worked. All I can answer is "Were these meant just to entertain troops in the field?" My answer is no, because "serious" people thought about using them in combat. I answered the question you posted six hours ago, which was not the version you just posted.

Comment: I just clarified my question, didn't change anything. All changes came after EDIT.

Comment: @andejons Pikes were used extensively by Russian conscripts repelling Napoleon's invasion in 1812.